# X axis not picking correct column for plot in pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have two column dataframe and i want to plot the data as already plot function is there in pandastable . 
How I can set the x axis column in pandastable plot. 
I am selecting two columns one as x axis & another as y axis , xaxis i want to be string time and y axis as value , 
Plot is coming correct but x axis is accepting as time column ,

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table
root=tk.Tk()
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00'],'value':[111,333,222,444],})

table_frame=tk.Frame(root)
table_frame.pack()

pt=Table(table_frame,dataframe=df,showstatusbar=True,showtoolbar=True)
pt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

I want my plot to take Time column as x axis & value as y axis in plot. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your string time column to be your x axis you can just group plot by time column data. That can be seen in the figure
[image: Plot]

Comment: I dont know how you are getting this perfect plot , Even after groupby Time i am not getting the xaxis as time :(

Comment: If you are running the same code and plotting by selecting total values from the table in it you should have to get it.Check if you are updated with the higher versions of the packages that you wanted to have in this exapmle. Even then if you are not getting mention your installed versions of all the packages that you wanted to have here.

Comment: Hi,
Can't i write any code which will by default do Groupby Time while plotting ?